# Dual screen problem with Optimus

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have a Lenovo T430 (with an Optimus graphical system), connected to a Dock Station with an output DVI (a 23" screen is on this output). I have Ubuntu 14.04 Beta 1.

Optimus works great with the last nVidia drivers (nvidia-331) and nvidia-prime.

With the command:

```
prime-select nvidia
```

I'm able to use the nvidia card rather than the Intel one. Note that the DVI port on the DockStation can be used only with the nVidia card !

The dual screen is nearly functional, I have my workspace on the two screens, and when I go in the parameters, I see correctly my two screens.

But, if I want to configure a little bit deeper, via nvidia-settings, it sees only the screen on the DVI port. So I cannot manage anything, and the problem is: the system thing I have only one screen. When a new window appears, it's between my two screens. When I "maximize" a window, it's done as if I had only one screen (so my window uses the two screens).

I'm not confident enough to edit xorg.conf or other things by myself, that's why I need your help.

Here a screenshot of the screen parameters settings from Ubuntu versus nvidia-settings:

[image]

Comment: Hi all,

I still have the problem, but now I maybe can be more precise. When I switch from the intel card to the nVidia one, I have this message :

`update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/nvidia-331-prime/ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode manuel
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/lib/nvidia-331-prime/alt_ld.so.conf » pour fournir « /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf » (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) en mode manuel`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem on W520 + dock. It was working fine in 14.04, but broke in 14.10. I tried to upgrade to nvidia-346, but it doesn't change anything.